# Apache won't allow symlink

Tags: php, apache, symlink, lithium

Seem to be getting an error related to my symlink in my browser pretty sure it is. I have ssh into my server and created the symlink (ln -s location/of/library new/symlink/location) which is how I would of do it on my local environment. when you list the files in my library folder it appears that the in red on my terminal which makes me think the sum link is made.... I have also tried to amended the apache conf file to make it allow  symlink to work but doesn't seem to work is this correct below, anyone know why am still getting an error.

```
# koa.url.co

<Directory /home/iacovos/app/koa/public>
       AllowOverride All
       Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName koa.url.co
   ServerAdmin webmaster@url.co
   DocumentRoot /home/iacovos/app/koa/public
   ErrorLog /home/iacovos/app/koa/log/error
   CustomLog /home/iacovos/app/koa/log/access common
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/iacovos/app/koa/cgi-bin

   <Directory /home/iacovos/app/koa/public/>
       Require all granted
       Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If it's showing as red it's because the link is broken. Apache won't work until you fix it

Comment: I ssh into my server, and ran the command `ln -s libraries/_source/Imagine/ libraries/Imagine`

Comment: correct me if am wrong but that is the correct method to create one